# Why Microsoft Graph MSAL SDK does not support Microsoft Emails(e.g. ****@hotmail.com, ****@live.com, ****@outlook.com) accounts to upload in Onedrive?

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create an iOS app which will upload photo to OneDrive using MSAL SDK for iOS. It works perfectly for users who login using other email domains except Microsoft like @gmail.com, @yahoo.com, @yandex.com works fine. But when using Microsoft email domains it does not upload photo. It sends status code = 404.

I have tested on multiple email accounts and seen that the problem persists for only Microsoft email accounts?

Any help to fix the issue will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for taking time to read my issue.

Comment: How is this problem related to the Swift programming language?

Comment: This problem was found when I was trying MSAL sdk on iOS app build on swift. I mentioned swift for that purpose.